# Slice numpy array with start position and offset back in the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I would like to slice a numpy array with a constant offset back in the array. I.e. start in the `k`'th position and go back `n` elements. I want to move the slight one index ahead at every iteration.

E.g. I have the following array

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

and let's say `k` is 5 and `n` is 3. That would give me the following (with ordering preserved)

```
x_sliced = [4, 5, 6]
```

In the next iteration `k += 1` and `n` is still 3. That gives me the following array

```
x_sliced = [5, 6, 7]
```

I can sort of get the result but I'll have to flip the array to get back to the original order. Isn't there a clever way that just uses a position and an offset back in the array?

Comment: What exactly is the *entire* output you would like to see? A list of lists, e.g. `[1,2,3]`, `[2,3,4]`..., `[8,9,10]`?

Comment: I think you can do `array[k:k+3]`

Comment: @7shoe yes, exactly. I want to run a for loop that uses a fixed sized array at every iteration, while changing part of the full array at every iteration.

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew yes, that was exactly it! I knew there was a simple solution to it. I would implement it as `x[k + i: k + i +n]` . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this could help:

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
k = 5
n = 3
view_as_windows(x[k-n+1:], n)
```

output:

```
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

Then you can loop over the output rows and process each window. One thing to note is that the overlapping windows share the same memory. If you wish that changing the values in one window does not affect the next overlapping window, simply copy it (`.copy()`)

Comment: `np.lib.stride_tricks` now has this `view..` function.

Comment: @hpaulj that is great. Thank you. is it the ```numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view```? this one seems to be missing the ```stride``` argument of the skimage method for a general case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) for that which requires no other dependencies than NumPy itself!

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (len(x)-3+1, 3), 2 * x.strides)

b
> array([[ 1,  2,  3],
         [ 2,  3,  4],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 4,  5,  6],
         [ 5,  6,  7],
         [ 6,  7,  8],
         [ 7,  8,  9],
         [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

Moreover, with `list(b)` you can turn the 2D array into a list of 1D arrays.